# I need to access the old value of ADF viewObject

Tags: oracle-adf

I have ADF page fragement (.jsff), which conatins ADF form based on ViewObject, I need to get the old value of af:RichInputField using EL expression, when I use:

#{bindings.fieldName.inputValue}, it gets the new submitted value, but what I need is the value before submission...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the valueChangeListener attribute (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21043_01/apirefs.1111/e12046/oracle/adf/view/js/event/AdfValueChangeEvent.html) of your af:RichInputField to trigger a java function in a bean that will get the new value and the old value for you to do whatever you want.

Here is a quick example with an inputText (It would work in a similar way with any ADF Faces input) :

```java
//In your jsff
<af:inputText value="#{bindings.YOUR_VO_BINDING_VALUE.inputValue}" 
    valueChangeListener="#{YOUR_BEAN_SCOPE.YOUR_BEAN.itChange}"
    id="it">
        <f:validator binding="#{bindings.YOUR_VO_BINDING_VALUE.validator}"/>
</af:inputText>

//In your YOUR_BEAN_SCOPE.YOUR_BEAN
public void itChange(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
    String oldValue = valueChangeEvent.getOldValue();
    String newValue = valueChangeEvent.getNewValue();
    
    //do whatever you want with those values
}
```

If you need to set a binding value in the [//do whatever you want with those values] please read https://cedricleruth.com/how-to-set-jsf-binding-attribute-programmatically-in-oracle-adf/ :

```java
JSFUtils.setExpressionValue("#{bindings.YOUR_VO_ATTRIBUTE.inputValue}",oldValue);
```